# This Change Programming Isn't Working

Tags: c

So here's my code. For some reason it always says that the amount of quarters is 4. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QUARTER 25      // Define the constant cent values of the quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.
#define DIME    10
#define NICKEL  5
#define PENNY   1

int main( void ){

    int priceOfitem;  // Initialize the variable that will be the price.
    printf("Enter the price of an item less than one dollar (in cents) (eg: 57) : ");
    scanf("%lg", &priceOfitem);

    if(priceOfitem >= 100){
    printf("The price must be less than one dollar. \nProgramming exiting.");
    return 0;
    }



    int changeAmount = 100 - priceOfitem; /* Create the variable that is the amount of change needed.
                                           * This variable will be modified later on.
                                           */

    int amountOfQuarters = ((changeAmount - (changeAmount % QUARTER)) / QUARTER); // Utilizing the modulus operator to determine the amount of quarters.

    printf("\n\nThe Amount of Quarters Needed in the Change is: %d", amountOfQuarters);

    changeAmount = changeAmount - (amountOfQuarters * QUARTER); // Modifying the change amount


    int amountOfDimes = ((changeAmount - (changeAmount % DIME)) / DIME); // Utilizing the modulus operator to determine the amount of dimes.

    printf("\n\nThe Amount of Dimes Needed in the Change is: %d", amountOfDimes);

    changeAmount = changeAmount - (amountOfDimes * DIME); // Modifying the change amount


    int amountOfNickels = ((changeAmount - (changeAmount % NICKEL)) / NICKEL); // Utilizing the modulus operator to determine the amount of nickels.

    printf("\n\nThe Amount of Nickels Needed in the Change is: %d", amountOfNickels);

    changeAmount = changeAmount - (amountOfNickels * NICKEL); // Modifying the change amount


    int amountOfPennies = changeAmount; // Since the changeAmount can now be expressed with pennies only, set the amountOfPennies variable as such.

    printf("\n\nThe Amount of Pennies Needed in the Change is: %d", amountOfPennies);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, where is the question? This is not a site for code review.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I think the question is pretty clear: `For some reason it always says that the amount of quarters is 4. What am I doing wrong?`

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
int priceOfitem;  // Initialize the variable that will be the price.
printf("Enter the price of an item less than one dollar (in cents) (eg: 57) : ");
scanf("%lg", &priceOfitem);
```

You need to pass `"%d"` to scanf for integer input:

```
scanf("%d", &priceOfitem);
```

Also you don't need this subtraction:

```
int changeAmount = priceOfitem; //int changeAmount = 100 - priceOfitem
```

Always use `-Wall -Werror` (or similar flags for your choice of compiler) when compiling.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a simple mistake I overlooked that ended up causing a huge logic error in my program! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer to your question but ...

Usually we calculate the number of quarters (and stuff like this) by just dividing using integer arithmetic, which throws away any fractional parts.

```
 int amountOfQuarters = changeAmount / QUARTER;
```

So, if changeAmount is 57 and we divide by 25 using integer arithmetic, we get 2.